# vba cast variant listbox / Objects

Tags: vba, object, casting, listbox, variant

I got an issue with "casting" variants to defined objects.

At runtime my variant variable is of type "Variant/Object/Listbox", which i then want to set to a ListBox variable to route it as a parameter to another function (GetSelected) that requires a Listbox object.

But I get the error 13: types incompatible on command "Set lst = v".

Any ideas how to get it working?

Code:

```
Function GetEditableControlsValues(EditableControls As Collection) As Collection
'Gibt die Werte der editierbaren Felder zurück.
Dim v As Variant
Dim coll As New Collection
Dim lst As ListBox

For Each v In EditableControls
    If TypeName(v) = "ListBox" Then
        Set lst = v     'Fehler 13: Typen unverträglich. v zur Laufzeit: Variant/Object/Listbox.
        coll.Add GetCollectionString(GetSelected(lst))
    Else
        coll.Add v.Value
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the Listbox as well? Cos I am wondering whether it is on a Form or on a WorkSheet.

Comment: It's on a MSForm.

I also tried to set the running variable to Control like "Dim ctl as control" instead of "Dim v as variant", but same error.

Comment: How do you call the Function and how the Collection of the EditableControls looks like?

Comment: The calling function is called as folllows:
`AddListObjectDataset ListObjects("GO_Tabelle"), GetEditableControlsValues(GetEditableControls)`

So the function is called as a parameter for another function (AddListObjects)

Comment: Try declaring your listbox as `Dim lst As msforms.ListBox`.

Comment: @Vityata I don't have the sub.  Did you mean to ask the OP?

Comment: Can you paste the whole Sub, using the function?

Comment: The declaration `Dim lst As msforms.ListBox` did the trick!
Thx guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have so far:

Imagine that you have a module with the following code in it:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim colInput        As New Collection
    Dim colResult       As Collection
    Dim lngCount        As Long
    Dim ufMyUf          As UserForm

    Set ufMyUf = UserForm1

    Set colInput = GetListBoxObjects(ufMyUf)

    For lngCount = 1 To colInput.Count
        Debug.Print colInput(lngCount).Name
    Next lngCount

End Sub

Function GetListBoxObjects(uf As UserForm) As Collection

    Dim colResult   As New Collection
    Dim objObj      As Object
    Dim ctrCont     As Control

    For Each ctrCont In uf.Controls
        If LCase(Left(ctrCont.Name, 7)) = "listbox" Then
            Set objObj = ctrCont
            colResult.Add objObj
        End If
    Next ctrCont

    Set GetListBoxObjects = colResult

End Function
```

If you run `TestMe`, you would get a collection of the `ListBox` objects. Anyhow, I am not sure how do you pass them to the collection function, thus I have decided to iterate over the UserForm and thus to check all of the objects on it.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with casting controls myself and didn't find a general solution that I could use easy.

Eventually I found the way to do it: store as "Object" makes it easy to convert to whatever type the control actually is.

I tested (and use) it

The sub below shows that it works (here : 1 TextBox; 1 ListBox; 1 ComboBox; 1 CommandButton on a worksheet)

```
Sub Test_Casting()
    Dim lis As MSForms.ListBox
    Dim txt As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim btn As MSForms.CommandButton
    Dim com As MSForms.ComboBox

    Dim numObjects As Integer: numObjects = Me.OLEObjects.Count
    Dim obj() As Object
    ReDim obj(1 To numObjects) As Object

    Dim i As Integer: i = 0

    Dim cttl As OLEObject
    For Each ctrl In Me.OLEObjects
        i = i + 1
        Set obj(i) = ctrl.Object
    Next ctrl

    Dim result As String
    For i = 1 To numObjects
        If TypeOf obj(i) Is MSForms.ListBox Then
            Set lis = obj(i): result = lis.Name
        ElseIf TypeOf obj(i) Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            Set txt = obj(i): result = txt.Name
        ElseIf TypeOf obj(i) Is MSForms.CommandButton Then
            Set btn = obj(i): result = btn.Name
        ElseIf TypeOf obj(i) Is MSForms.ComboBox Then
            Set ComboBox = obj(i): result = com.Name
        Else
            result = ""
        End If
        If (Not (result = "")) Then Debug.Print TypeName(obj(i)) & "  name= " & result
    Next i

    For i = 1 To numObjects
        Set lis = IsListBox(obj(i))
        Set txt = IsTextBox(obj(i))
        Set btn = IsCommandButton(obj(i))
        Set com = IsComboBox(obj(i))
        result = ""
        If (Not (lis Is Nothing)) Then
            result = "ListBox " & lis.Name
        ElseIf (Not (txt Is Nothing)) Then
            result = "TexttBox " & txt.Name
        ElseIf (Not (btn Is Nothing)) Then
            result = "CommandButton " & btn.Name
        ElseIf (Not (com Is Nothing)) Then
            result = "ComboBox " & com.Name
        End If
        Debug.Print result
    Next i
End Sub

Function IsListBox(obj As Object) As MSForms.ListBox
    Set IsListBox = IIf(TypeOf obj Is MSForms.ListBox, obj, Nothing)
End Function

Function IsTextBox(obj As Object) As MSForms.TextBox
    Set IsTextBox = IIf(TypeOf obj Is MSForms.TextBox, obj, Nothing)
End Function

Function IsComboBox(obj As Object) As MSForms.ComboBox
    Set IsComboBox = IIf(TypeOf obj Is MSForms.ComboBox, obj, Nothing)
End Function

Function IsCommandButton(obj As Object) As MSForms.CommandButton
    Set IsCommandButton = IIf(TypeOf obj Is MSForms.CommandButton, obj, Nothing)
End Function
```

One use for it is a class for handling events in one class.

```
Private WithEvents intEvents As IntBoxEvents
Private WithEvents decEvents As DecBoxEvents

Private genEvents As Object
Private genControl as OLEobject

Public sub Delegate(ctrl As OLEObject)
    set genControl = ctrl 
    ' Code for creating intEvents or decEvents 
    if .... create intevents.... then set genEvents = new IntEvents ' pseudo code
    if .... create decevents.... then set genEvents = new DecEvents ' pseudo code
end sub
```

I hope this helps others that struggle with casting controls